# Não consigo enxergar o erro (PHP e HTML)

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Queria mostrar os nomes dos funcionários e as equipes que os mesmos fazem parte de forma que se o usuário digitar um nome, filtrará todas as equipes que aquela pessoa faz parte.
Está vindo em branco.

```
   try{

                        $pdo = Conexao::getInstance();

                      $consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_equipe,nome_equipe,GROUP_CONCAT(nome_eletricista) as equipes FROM quadro WHERE id_agencia=:id AND status=1 GROUP BY nome_equipe ORDER BY nome_equipe ASC");

                        $consulta->bindParam(':id',$id_agencia, PDO::PARAM_INT);

                         if($consulta->execute()){

                          if($consulta->rowCount() > 0){

                          while($dados = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

                                      $id_equipe= $dados['id_equipe'];
                                      $nome= $dados['nome_equipe'];
                                      $equipe= $dados->nome_equipe;
                                      $equipes=$dados->equipes;


                                      echo'<option value="'.$id_equipe.'">'.$nome.' - '.$equipes.'</option>';

                                          }
                                    }       
                                  }
                    }catch(PDOexception $e){

                        echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
                      }

                ?>
                              </select>
                              <br>
```

Comment: Quando você executa a `query` no terminal ou *PHPMyAdmin*, ela traz algum resultado?

Comment: Opa! Dá um erro: #1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'empresa_db.quadro.id_equipe' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O servidor *MySQL* pode operar em diferentes modos *SQL* e pode aplicar esses modos de forma diferente para diferentes clientes, dependendo do valor da variável `sql_mode` do sistema.

O erro `only_full_group_by` é gerado quando você utiliza um valor não agregado em uma *query* que possui `GROUP BY`.

Há duas formas de corrigir:

- Utilizando `ANY_VALUE`

```
$consulta = $pdo->prepare("SELECT ANY_VALUE(id_equipe), nome_equipe, ANY_VALUE(GROUP_CONCAT(nome_eletricista)) AS equipes FROM quadro WHERE id_agencia=:id AND status=1 GROUP BY nome_equipe ORDER BY nome_equipe ASC");
```

- Desabilitando `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` ao instanciar o objeto do PDO.

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1", "root", "123456", [
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,"ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY",""));'
]);
```

Comment: Ok, vou tentar a query. Mas estou com outro problema, esse script SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,"ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY",""));' Deixou minha tela do formulário travada. Sabe como voltar ao estado anterior?

Comment: @IsadoraAlmeida o problema é que você executou ele de forma `GLOBAL`, isso só deve ser feito quando se tem — realmente — certeza do que está fazendo. Caso você queira fazer o `rollback`, basta executar: `SET GLOBAL sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'`. Ps: Faça o backup antes de qualquer modificação global.

Comment: Não corrigiu. :(
mas obrigada

Comment: @IsadoraAlmeida o que não corrigiu? A query ou o rollback?

Comment: Descobri aqui: o anyvalue que estava dando problema. Não estava reconhecendo. Pensei que havia sido a váriavel global.

Comment: Ainda não consegui mostrar as informações no select. Se tiver mais alguma ideia, agradeço. Consigo direto no banco, mas não na aplicação.

Comment: @IsadoraAlmeida você chegou a tentar da segunda forma, porém usando o `select` sem o `ANY_VALUE`?

Comment: Opa! Consegui resolver sim. O problema era o DISTINCT.

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda @Valdeir Psr

Answer (score 0):

desabilitando o sql_mode.

Faz assim:

mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));

Comment: Opa! Esse script resolve o select no banco, mas não na aplicação. E não mostrando todos os campos do form.

Comment: Existe a possibilidade de dar rollback desse script?Porque a tela ficou travada, depois dessa excução no banco.

Comment: qual a versão do mysql que está usando?

Comment: 5.7.14 Mas uso a função CONCAT em outra lista e funciona normalmente.